# Dense_Rank function not work

Tags: oracle, oracle-analytics

I have a below query :

```
select id, firstname,LastName,Company, dense_rank() over (partition by company order by id ) 

from UserAdditionalData 

where Company is not null
```

Here is the result that I am getting: http://prntscr.com/a9d454.
Dense_Rank function is not working,please help me in this.

Comment: can you provide some example data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I have given url above.

Comment: In what respect is the result not what you expected?

Comment: @Ed,What I want is that partition by company.But ,If the company is same then last column value remains the same for same company.

Comment: It is working - the rows have been partitioned by `company` and within each partition there is a (dense) rank for each row in ascending order of `id` - exactly what the query asked for. If this is not your desired behaviour then you will need to write an appropriate query to ask for that behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

> What I want is that partition by company.But ,If the company is same then last column value remains the same for same company.

That is not partitioning by company - in fact it requires no partitioning at all.

What you want is:

```
SELECT id,
       firstname,
       LastName,
       Company,
       dense_rank() over ( order by company ) AS Company_Rank
FROM   UserAdditionalData 
WHERE  Company IS NOT NULL
```